# The method setStdGPA(Float) in the type StudentBean is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java

How to solve this error by conversion float to String,
my code is here

```
private StudentBean prepareStudentBean(Student student){
    StudentBean bean = new StudentBean();
    bean.setStdId(student.getStdId());
    bean.setStdName(student.getStdName());
    bean.setStdClass(student.getStdClass());
    bean.setStdGPA(student.getStdGPA());
    return bean;
}
```

The method setStdGPA(Float) in the type StudentBean is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: `Float.valueOf(student.getStdGPA());`

Comment: Thanks problem Solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
bean.setStdGPA(Float.valueOf(student.getStdGPA());
```